# Dynamic subdomain pointing to html folder

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, subdomain

I have a PHP script that takes the subdomain i.e blah.example.com and runs a query based on that.

The problem I have is that I can't get my new server to route any subdomain that someone may type to the HTML folder to run that command.

I can't manually add the subdomains since I wont know them so I want to be able to set it so that the user can enter https://anything.example.com and the script runs.

I'm using Apache 2.4 on CENTOS 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your `<VirtualHost>` you can set a `ServerAlias` that uses a wildcard hostname. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

Note that it must be a `ServerAlias`. The `ServerName` must be a fully qualified domain name and cannot have wildcards. It is the primary name for that virtual host.